# Align rotated Text to center

Tags: css

Is it possible to align a rotated text to center?

For example here:

[image]
ill try using:

```
.accordion div.image .title {
    bottom: -15px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    white-space: normal;
    left: 20px; // this is only the way to center it from left corner }
```

But when the text has a line break, i have no chance to align it to the center.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a snippet or at least jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Sure, i will create that later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach (proof of concept) that involves using the `translate` function of the `transform` property and `display: table-cell`.

First, use `display: inline-block` on the parent container to get a shrink-to-fit to the image size (or else specify fixed dimensions if you can).

You then define an absolutely positioned container to contain the label.  I fixed the width and height (this makes things easier) and then rotated and translated the box to center it within the parent.

Finally, I used `vertical-align: middle` in the nested table-cell container to allow multiple lines of text to remain centered.

If you are adding this to a pre-existing HTML/CSS structure (accordion?), you need to make the CSS very specific so that you don't break other CSS styling.

You may still need to make some adjustments depending on how you want the bottom of the label to be positioned and so on.

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
.image img {
    display: block;
}
div.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.image .title {
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: normal;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;   
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(50%,50%);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x400">
    <div class="title"><div class="cell">The title text
        that can span two lines or more in a box<div></div>
</div>
```